# Change function without filter hook

Tags: functions

I would like to modfify function.php and other files.
There's no filter hook. How can I change functions without filter hook?
I thought,

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'function_name' ) {
       function_name () {
              ...
       }
}
```

Could you recommend the way to rewrite the function? Many thanks.

Comment: please be more specific. your idea would only work if the original function is defined that way already. see 'pluggable functions'

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Michael
I read this git regarding rewriting wp_mail function: https://github.com/humanmade/aws-ses-wp-mail/blob/master/aws-ses-wp-mail.php
I was wondering how this works with, and as you stated, it may be related with 'pluggable functions'. I'm searching about that. 
Thank you so much!

So, if I would like to change functions in Wordpress, filter hook is the only way without pluggable functions? :)